# How do I stop an image at the bottom of the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(".raindrop1").clone().removeClass("raindrop1").addClass("raindropDelete").appendTo("body").css({
  left: $(".shape").position().left - 29.50,
  top: $(".shape").position().top + 1,
  position: "relative"
}).animate({
  top: "+=1000"
}, function() {
  $(".raindropDelete").remove();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.shape {
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shape" onclick="curse()"></div>
<img src='http://images.clipartpanda.com/raindrop-clipart-RTGdn5bTL.png' width="15px" class="raindrop1">
```

I got this bit of code but I just can't seem to get it to work the way I want to. I want to make an image fall down to the bottom of the screen but to delete itself just before a scrollbar appears.

JS:

```
$(".raindrop1").clone().removeClass("raindrop1").addClass("raindropDelete").appendTo("body").css({
                left: $(".shape").position().left - 29.50,
                top: $(".shape").position().top + 1,
                position: "relative"
            }).animate({top :"+=1000"}, function() {
                $(".raindropDelete").remove();
            });
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "shape" onclick = "curse()"></div>
<img src = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/raindrop-clipart-RTGdn5bTL.png' width = "15px" class = "raindrop1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and CSS:

```
body{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.shape{
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/os3pwxdu/)

Comment: Could you please add a web code snippet, with your HTML, CSS and Javascript code in it. It allows us to see directly what is wrong with your code by executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to remove your droplet in the function that is used to do something when animation is completed. So droplet animation is still going until it will reach +1000px from the top.

To remove before it falls below the window it's possible to use `step` option for `animate` method. What it does is looking what happens during animation and you can remove the droplet if when it falls below the edge.

> **Step Function**
>
> The second version of .animate() provides a step option — a callback
>   function that is fired at each step of the animation. This function is
>   useful for enabling custom animation types or altering the animation
>   as it is occurring. It accepts two arguments (now and fx), and this is
>   set to the DOM element being animated.
>
> - now: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step
> - fx: a reference to the jQuery.fx prototype object, which contains a number
>     of properties such as elem for the animated element, start and end for
>     the first and last value of the animated property, respectively, and
>     prop for the property being animated.

So what I've done is created a step function that each step looks if droplet is reached the edge of the window. If condition is met - just remove the droplet

```js
$(".raindrop1").clone()
 .removeClass("raindrop1")
  .addClass("raindropDelete")
  .appendTo("body").css({
     left: $(".shape").position().left - 29.50,
     top: $(".shape").position().top + 1,
     position: "relative"
    })
    .animate({top :"+=100"}, 
             {step: function(now) {
               if (now+50 >= $(window).height())
                $(".raindropDelete").remove();
               }
              },
     function() {});
```

```css
body{
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.shape{
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "shape" onclick = "curse()"></div>
  <img src = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/raindrop-clipart-RTGdn5bTL.png' width = "15px" class = "raindrop1">
```

Answer (score 0):

using this `css` you can stick your image to the bottom of the window in all new browsers

```
    .fix{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
    }
<img src="yourimagepath" class="fix"/>
```

and for IE6 you can use
`position:absolute;` instead of fixed. It will position the image on the bottom of the page but as you scroll up the image will scroll with the page. Unfortunately `position:fixed` in not supported in IE6

Using this code you can detect if the user has reached to the bottom of the page. Here you can add your code for deleting the image. If you put the code here the image will be deleted automatic if the user reaches to the bottom of the page.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
   if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    // you're at the bottom of the page
   }
};
```

Comment: I want to just point out that i want the image to delete itself once it has moved down to the bottom of the window.

Comment: Please check again my answer. I have add something.

Comment: @Fotis Grigorakis it won't solve author's problem because it's not what he is asking. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/os3pwxdu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sticky elements. They are elements on a page that will not be scrolled out of view. In other words it sticks to a visible area (viewport or scrolling box). You can create this with CSS using position: sticky;.

[Ref: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-css-tricks-you-might-have-overlooked/]

Look at the following code for an example:

https://codepen.io/rpsthecoder/pen/zGYXEX

HTML:

```
<h4>Scroll to see the sticky element <em>sticking</em></h4>
<div class="extra"></div>
<br />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sticky">
    sticky
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="extra"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#sticky {
  position: sticky;
  background: #F762BC;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 70px;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff
}

#wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.extra{
  background: #ccc;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
  font-family: georgia;
}
h4{
  text-align: center;
}
```